# com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value New of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, frontend, android-volley

Working on Android Studio and IntelliJ for mobile dev, and when working on a signup page, after sending the request I get this error

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value New of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

but the issue is that i can see on the backend that it is saving the user and giving a 200 OK response

```
POST "/people", parameters={}
Mapped to coms309.people.PeopleController#createPerson(Person)
Read "application/json;charset=utf-8" to [5 dave borucki dave@mail.com dunk]
5 dave borucki dave@mail.com dunk
Using 'text/plain', given [*/*] and supported [text/plain, */*, application/json, application/*+json]
Writing ["New person dave Saved"]
Completed 200 OK
```

This is what my AS frontend code looks like.

```
package com.example.androidexample;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText firstNameEditText;
    private EditText lastNameEditText;
    private EditText emailAddressEditText;
    private EditText passwordEditText;
    private Button signupButton;
    private Button loginButton;
    private JSONObject user;
    private static final String URL_SIGNUP =  "http://10.0.2.2:8081/people";
    private EditText errorEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);


        /* initialize UI elements */
        firstNameEditText = findViewById(R.id.signup_firstName_edt);  // link to username edtext in the Signup activity XML
        lastNameEditText = findViewById(R.id.signup_lastName_edt);  // link to password edtext in the Signup activity XML
        emailAddressEditText = findViewById(R.id.signup_email_edt);    // link to confirm edtext in the Signup activity XML
        passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.signup_password_edt);    // link to login button in the Signup activity XML
        signupButton = findViewById(R.id.signup_signup_btn);  // link to signup button in the Signup activity XML
        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.signup_login_btn);
        errorEditText = findViewById(R.id.errorText);

        /* click listener on login button pressed */
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                /* when login button is pressed, use intent to switch to Login Activity */
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);  // go to LoginActivity
            }
        });

        /* click listener on signup button pressed */
        signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                /* grab strings from user inputs */
                String firstName = firstNameEditText.getText().toString();
                String lastName = lastNameEditText.getText().toString();
                String emailAddress = emailAddressEditText.getText().toString();
                String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("Signup pressed");
                user = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    user.put("id", 5);
                    user.put("firstName", firstName);
                    user.put("lastName", lastName);
                    user.put("emailAddress", emailAddress);
                    user.put("password", password);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                signUpRequest();
            }
        });
    }
    private void signUpRequest() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                URL_SIGNUP,
                user,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Account Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent successIntent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        //successIntent.putExtra("id", id);
                        startActivity(successIntent);
                    }
                },new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Signup unsuccessful (VolleyError)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                errorEditText.setText(error.toString());
            }
        });
        queue.add(request);
    }
}
```

I tried rearranging where the JSON Object is supposed to be, i made it before to where it was inside of the signupRequest() function

Comment: what is the raw response of that endpoint? I.e. when you request using cUrl etc?

Comment: daveborucki@dborucki ~ % curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      -d '{ "id":5,"firstName":"dave", "lastName":"borucki","emailAddress":"dave@mail.com","password":"pass123"}' \
      -X POST \
      http://127.0.0.1:8081/people
New person dave Saved

Comment: So clearly the response is not json

Answer (score 0):

you can see

> public void onResponse(JSONObject response)

this void will be taking data as json and the response which your server prints is not a json format as i can see it prints

> COMPLETED 200 OK

you can change your Server Side response format to a json like

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "message": "COMPLETED OK"
}
```

Hope It Helps!